# Google plus shares wrong title from post

Tags: php, wordpress, google-plus, title, wordpress-thesis-theme

If you try sharing via Google+ most of the articles on this WordPress site: appgo2market.com
you'll noticed that title when Google+ is wrong when trying to share.
This happens also if you cut and paste link to a post on your personal Google+ account for sharing.

I didn't see yet, any relation to what may need to be done on a WordPress site to solve this.

Any idea what needs to be done, on a WordPress site, using thesis2, to solve this?

Comment: I checked the api from Thesis 2 and did not see anything about social sharing.  Is that a plugin you are using or does the theme come with the sharing functions built in?

Comment: Thesis provide boxes. G+ is one of their boxes, but, that doesn't seem to be a thesis related issue, as even if you go to your personal google+ account, and just try to share on of the posts, you'll still get wrong title. It probably relates to the site tags/schema, like Ian mentions on Answer (1), the issue is I don't really understand what's required for a wordpress site with thesis.

Comment: Insert Open-Graph data into your side. Without an example/live preview we can only speculate!

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance... while I can get my hands dirty, the RTFM side of doing things I never did is a bit hard for me. The live example is: http://appgo2market.com - most of the posts there would show wrong title if trying to share on google plus. I am not familiar how to utilize open graph, on a wordpress platform with thesis 2 installed. If you could please be a bit more specific, that would help a lot. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like many of the pages are behind a "become a member" section, which is the title I see being picked up. The title for the share can be controlled by adding schema.org markup, or by changing the title tag of the page. Take a look at this page for more details: https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/

Comment: Thanks Ian. I actually tried reading that, but I'm not sure how to take the google explanations into practice on a wordpress site with thesis2 installed. I was expecting the general case to just work out of the box. Maybe there's a plugin that is interfering (though I tried turning them all off). Maybe W3 total cache was doing something ? I'm not sure even how to start...

Comment: You only need to add a prefix to your HTML-Tag like `<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">` and the Title in the Header: `<meta property="og:title" content="<?php wp_title(); ?>" />`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure though where to do that in the wordpress platform (with thesis 2). I have various hooks I can use php to add stuff, but I'm not sure where to actually add this in wordpress/thesis/php hooks. Any advice regarding that ? thank you in advance.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://www.byobwebsite.com/forum/all-things-google/google-is-taking-the-wrong-title-per-post/#p23899